# Select similar rows from a table given a table of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables.

```
Table A

+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID | First | Middle | Last  | Time  |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| 1  | John  | Alan   | Smith | 12:38 |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| 2  | John  | Alan   | Smith | 1:24  |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| 3  | John  | Alan   | Bauer | 1:24  |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| 4  | Sam   | Paul   | West  | 10:04 |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+

Table B

+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 4  |
+----+
```

From this, I need to create a `SELECT` query to get the rows of Table A with `First`, `Middle` and `Last` values that match the `First`, `Middle` and `Last` values for the `ID`s in Table B.

In other words, I need to get

```
Table C

+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| ID | First | Middle | Last  | Time  |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| 1  | John  | Alan   | Smith | 12:38 |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| 2  | John  | Alan   | Smith | 1:24  |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| 4  | Sam   | Paul   | West  | 10:04 |
+----+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

So we selected row 2 and row 4, since they were in Table B, but we also selected row 1 because its `First`, `Middle` and `Last` values matched those in row 2.

We didn't select row 3 because its `Last` value wasn't in any of the rows from Table B.

I hope this makes sense. I'm not sure how to go about this. I was thinking about using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on A and B, but then I wasn't sure how to select the similar rows from there.

Comment: can you please tell me how did you draw your data so nicely? in the ascii table thing?

Comment: @I__ - Mark it as code to get the fixed-width font when it's displayed.

Comment: @root45, Most of the answers here use subqueries or full joins, both of which are slower than left joins. See my answer for how to do this using only left joins, should be more efficient than the posted alternatives.

Comment: @Dems i dont know if that's the case. if so, then it would have taken him like an hour to post the question

Comment: @I__ - Not usre why you think it's an hour to hit `+`, `-` and `|` a bunch of times, then use copy and paste.  But marking an area as code *is* how to get fixed-width characters, and then it's easy to align everything neatly.

Comment: @dems thats insane. i believe you. is there a service that will do this for you of which you might be aware?

Comment: @I__, the mysql command line outputs its tables just like this. He probably just copied and pasted the output for "select * from a;" and "select * from b;", then just removed a couple lines to get the desired table c display.

Comment: @BenLee i dont think so. this is tagged sql server

Comment: @root45 can you please answer our question

Comment: @I__, you're right. I actually didn't even look at the tag; I saw the table output like that and immediately thought "MySQL" so didn't bother checking...

Comment: @BenLee so what do u think it is? do you think he really took the time to format this?

Comment: @I__ Sorry for the delay in response. Dems is correct, I did do this by hand and it took me some time (although not an hour, maybe 5 or 10 minutes). Ben is also correct that MySQL will output tables like this, so you could quickly create sample tables and copy the output. I'm using SQL Server though, and it was quicker to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select A.* from TableA A
inner join TableA A2 on A.First = A2.First and A.Middle = A2.Middle and A.Last = A2.Last
and A2.ID in (select ID from TableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select *
from TableA a
where exists
(select null
 from TableA a1
 join TableB b on a1.ID = b.ID
 where a.First = a1.First and a.Middle = a1.Middle and a.Last = a1.Last)
```

Comment: I think you forgot the word 'Inner' before the word 'Join'

Comment: @TimLarson: Without a qualifier, joins default to inner joins. So no, I didn't forget. :)

Comment: @MarkBannister, you're right of course, but I'd argue it's a best practice to specify "INNER" anyway, just to make it explicit for people reading the code who may not be aware of the default.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use full inner joins or sub-queries. A table alias and two left joins will do this for you, and I believe this is more efficient than any of the other posted alternatives. See here for proof this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11361/1

```
SELECT c.*
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN a AS c ON
  c.first = a.first AND
  c.middle = a.middle AND
  c.last = a.last
```

This is actually constructing something very much like the table c you are looking for and the selecting all the rows from it (`SELECT c.*`).

And it follows the same logic as the way you think about it:

- Start with the ids from table b (`FROM b`).
- Look for the corresponding rows in table a (`LEFT JOIN a ON b.id = a.id`).
- Finally, select all rows from table a that also match (`LEFT JOIN a AS c ON c.first = a.first AND c.middle = a.middle AND c.last = a.last`).
- That's it, you now have a table c that looks just like what you want.

Comment: This will return only the IDs (from table B).  He wanted several fields returned.

Comment: @TimLarson, no it will return exactly what he posted as what he wants. Note I am selecting `c.*`, not anything from `b`.

Comment: @TimLarson, yeah I just discovered it yesterday. Love it!

Comment: @BenLee I upvoted your answer. I think I'm ultimately going to use aF.'s because it's slightly easier to read, and performance isn't really a concern here (my tables will be small). But I do appreciate the time you took to write a nice query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT    TA2.ID,
          TA2.First,
          TA2.Middle,
          TA2.Last,
          TA2.Time
FROM      TableA AS TA INNER JOIN
          TableB AS TB ON TB.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN
          TableA AS TA2 ON TA2.First = TA.First AND
              TA2.Middle = TA.Middle AND
              TA2.Last = TA.Last
```

Comment: There is no TB2 defined anywhere

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A2.ID, A2.First, A2.Middle, A2.Last, A2.Time
FROM A AS A
INNER JOIN B AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN A AS A2 ON
    A.First = A2.First AND
    A.Middle = A2.Middle AND
    A.Last = A2.Last
```